# Changing properties of user control from another page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, pagination

I have a user control called "DashboardUserControl.ascx"

It has a function:

```
public void setPagination(Boolean pagination)
    {
        this.DashboardGridView.AllowPaging = pagination;
    }
```

I have two other pages with that user control inserted via drag and drop:

1. MyDashboard.aspx: I want to set the pagination of user control to "true" from this page.
2. SharedDashboard.aspx: I want to set the pagination of the user control to "false".

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the usercontrol added to both pages, then you have two instances of the usercontrol. Which means the usercontrol on the pages are not connected.

So to call the method, you can simple do the following in the Page_Load of the pages. The following code sample is for MyDashboard.aspx.cs. Change *true* to *false* in SharedDashboard.aspx.cs.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.DashboardUserControl.setPagination(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution you gave last week. It did not work. Now I tried it again and it works. I must have done something else wrong last time around. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either you:

- Put a call to setPagination in the code behind of MyDashboard.aspx and SharedDashboard.aspx with the boolean value set according to each page's requirements.

Or (which I would prefer)

- Rewrite the method to be a property:

  `public bool Pagination
      {
          set { this.DashboardGridView.AllowPaging = value; }
          get { return this.DashboardGridView.AllowPaging; }
      }`

If you add the property you can assign a value to it in *either* from code behind or from the markup of MyDashboard.aspx and SharedDashboard.aspx. 
E.g. `<uc:MyControl id="myControl1" Pagination="true" runat="server" />`

Hope this helps